# NDB ordering by property of specific instance of repeated StructuredProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In a an app for cars history I have to create different charts where some models may be present in one or more different charts as "fastest car", "best car", etc. Then they have to be ordered in the chart. I have used StructuredProperty to create tag name/order position pairs.

```
class CarTag(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    position = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Car(ndb.Model):
    model_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    trim = ndb.StringProperty()
    year = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    tags = ndb.StructuredProperty(CarTag, repeated=True)
```

The filter on the structured property works fine.

```
cars = Car.query(Car.tags.name=="fastest car")
```

But to get the ordered chart I need to order them by the position property of the same StructuredProperty which name is "fastest car". As I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966098/ndb-ordering-by-property-of-structuredproperty) order(Car.tags.position) will order only by the first element of the list.

```
cars = Car.query(Car.tags.name==name).order(Car.tags.position)
```

Is it possible to order by property of specific StructuredProperty?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I doubt this is possible.  You *could* always sort after the fact in python though.  If the amount of data is small enough that you don't need to page through your query (which is likely true as you're making a chart with the results), you could just sort the results in python with an appropriate sort key...

Comment: Yes I doubt as well. And you are right - the data is small enough. I will do it this way but I wanted to know if there is better way. Thanks Matt!

Comment: Build separated index for your car tags, do you don't have to use structured property. You could even use store only a key like "name.position.car_id" then you can filter by key prefix to get all cars with specified name and they will be ordered by default by position as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that you can't order by a property inside of a StructuredProperty, it's that your StructuredProperty is repeated=True... making it a list-property.. and you can't reliably sort on a list-property:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#properties_with_multiple_values_can_behave_in_surprising_ways

> **Properties with multiple values can behave in surprising ways**
>
> Because of the way they're indexed, entities with multiple values for
>   the same property can sometimes interact with query filters and sort
>   orders in unexpected and surprising ways.
>
> .....
>
> If the query results are sorted in ascending order, the smallest value
>   of the property is used for ordering. If the results are sorted in
>   descending order, the greatest value is used for ordering. Other
>   values do not affect the sort order, nor does the number of values.
>   This has the unusual consequence that an entity with property values 1
>   and 9 precedes one with values 4, 5, 6, and 7 in both ascending and
>   descending order.